# Nutch not deleting duplicates from Solr

Tags: solr, duplicates, nutch

When Nutch finishes its crawl it recognises that there are duplicates to delete and goes through saying "deleting xxx duplicates" and completes with no problems.  The only problem is that it actually hasnt deleted the duplicates although it said it has.

I've also tried using the dedup command on its own and the result is the same.

I have Solr & Nutch Set-up as shown on my blog if you wish to delve a little deeper, each stage in a different post:

http://amac4.blogspot.co.uk/2013/07/setting-up-solr-with-apache-tomcat-be.html
http://amac4.blogspot.co.uk/2013/07/setting-up-nutch-to-crawl-filesystem.html

Comment: Once the crawl is complete, Nutch runs its own deduplication facility that doesn't ask or require me to commit anything, it is all automated

Comment: do you have a master slave replication? ther are not enough info to proceed here I think

Comment: I dont beleive I do have master slave replication.  I added the links to my blog if you want to check it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the signatureField tag I had "id" instead of "signature"

```
<updateRequestProcessorChain name="dedupe">
  <processor class="org.apache.solr.update.processor.SignatureUpdateProcessorFactory">
    <bool name="enabled">true</bool>
    <bool name="overwriteDupes">true</bool>
    <str name="signatureField">signature</str>
    <str name="fields">id</str>
    <str name="signatureClass">org.apache.solr.update.processor.Lookup3Signature</str>
  </processor>
  <processor class="solr.LogUpdateProcessorFactory" />
  <processor class="solr.RunUpdateProcessorFactory" />
</updateRequestProcessorChain>
```

Works perfectly now